# VS 2013 hangs after installing nodejs extension and visual stuio code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-code, activitylog

i have visual studio 2013 update 4 installed. Recently i have installed node.js extension for VS 2013. It was working fine. Then i have also installed Visual Studio Code. But that caused VS 2013 to hang at startup

I have tried uninstalling Visual Studio Code. But still VS 2013 hangs at startup.

here are the last 5 entries in ActivityLog.xml

```
</activity>
       .
       .
       .
       .
     <entry>
        <record>1065</record>
        <time>2016/03/16 16:02:44.666</time>
        <type>Information</type>
        <source>VisualStudio</source>
        <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
        <guid>{FE8A8C3D-328A-476D-99F9-2A24B75F8C7F}</guid>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <record>1066</record>
        <time>2016/03/16 16:02:44.666</time>
        <type>Information</type>
        <source>VisualStudio</source>
        <description>Begin package load [NodejsPackage]</description>
        <guid>{FE8A8C3D-328A-476D-99F9-2A24B75F8C7F}</guid>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <record>1067</record>
        <time>2016/03/16 16:02:44.672</time>
        <type>Information</type>
        <source>VisualStudio</source>
        <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <record>1068</record>
        <time>2016/03/16 16:02:44.672</time>
        <type>Information</type>
        <source>VisualStudio</source>
        <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
        <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <record>1069</record>
        <time>2016/03/16 16:02:44.808</time>
        <type>Information</type>
        <source>VisualStudio</source>
        <description>End package load [NodejsPackage]</description>
        <guid>{FE8A8C3D-328A-476D-99F9-2A24B75F8C7F}</guid>
      </entry>
    </activity>
```

Now how do i uninstall Node.js extension since i cannot even start VS

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have found a solution by now, but I ran into the same issue with VS 2013 and Node.js, in particular after I installed the tools, Nodejs Tools for Visual Studio (Version 1.1 if I recall). Although it is unclear of the actual cause it did coincide and removing the tools did resolve the start up issue.

I was receiving a pernicious "Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an operation to complete" error on most of my projects and the system would hang and not respond. I was able to find a small (very simple "hello world") Node.js application that did load and allow VS to become responsive again. None of my C# or other solutions/projects worked nor did simply starting it from the command line.  The log file in my case was not indicative of any issue.

**Solution:**
Tools --> Extensions and Updates indicated that the Node.js Tools needed to be uninstalled via the Control Panel.  After removing the application via the Control Panel/Programs and Features the issue resolved itself.  But I no longer have access to the Node.js tools. Guess it is back to vim...

I have not installed Update 5 as of yet but there is no indication that this is necessary. I will try again after the Update to see if it resolves any issues and will report back if it does.